# concatenate two CSV files using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, scikit-learn

i have multiple CSV files that contain various patients features and hour measure that represent the time of recording this measurement as follows

```
file 1
    Subject_id    hour_measure   label               valuenum
    23                1          heart_rate             45
    23                2          respiratory_rate       21
    24                1          heart_rate             40
    24                2          respiratory_rate       22


file 2
    Subject_id    hour_measure   label               valuenum
    23                1          Temperature            20           
    23                2          Blood_pressure         130      
    24                1          Temperature            29           
    24                2          Blood_pressure         50
```

i want to concatenate the two files to be as follows

```
Subject_id  hour_measure  heart rate respiratory_rate  Blood pressure temperature  
  23                1               45           21              130    30 
       
  24                1               40           22               50    29
```

i use the following code

```
  df= pd.read_csv('data.csv',low_memory=False, error_bad_lines = False)

#df.dtypes
# reshape when columns are only number
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=[hour_measure','subject_id'],
                             columns=['label'],values=['valuenum'])

with open('test.csv', 'a',newline='') as f: 
    df1.to_csv(f, header=True)
```

but unfortunately it create the file as follows

```
label                             valuenum       valuenum
  Subject_id    hour_measure    heart_rate      Respiratory_rate
    23                1               45          21
    24                2               40          22
label                             valuenum       valuenum
  Subject_id    hour_measure    Blood_pressure   Temprature
    23               1               130           20
    24               2               50            29
```

So please id any one could help me how to fix this problem
any help will be appreciated

Comment: can you check/edit your desired outcome?  The numbers in it do not appear to be traceable back to the sample data.  Also, is "hour_measure" a representation of different times or a numerical index of the measurements taken at a particular time?  Specifically, it isn't clear how in your result data you have 2 'heart_rate' measurements for each subject, when only 1 is reported in the orig data.

Comment: yes , you are right. i write the numbers just to deliver my idea.. regrading to hour_measure, it represent that the measurement have been taken

Comment: Still isn't clear or consistent.  How do you get two measurements for subject 23 for heart rate?

Comment: please see it know, i correct the numbers to make it consistent

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do

```
pd.concat([
    pd.read_csv(f)
    for f in ("file1.csv", "file2.csv")
]).pivot_table(index=['hour_measure','subject_id'],
                         columns=['label'],values=['valuenum'] ).to_csv("concat_file.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: i need to make the concatenation based on Subject_id and hour measure as an index... could you tell me how ?

Comment: Right. You need to run pivot after concatenation. I'll edit my answer in a minute.  Done.